# Rails 5 Model Association has_many :through, validate child can only belong to one parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

3 models in question. Outage, Child, Relationship.

An outage can have many children.
A child belongs to an outage.
Relationship is the middleman table.

A child can only belong to ONE outage at a time (ie, if child 123 belongs to outage A, you cant associate child 123 with a different outage)

The children in each outage must be unique. (I've solved this with `validates_uniqueness_of` in the `Relationship` model).

```
class Outage < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :relationships
    has_many :children, :through => :relationships
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :relationships
    has_many :outages, :through => :relationships 
end

class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :outage
    belongs_to :child
    validates_uniqueness_of :outage_id, :scope => :child_id
end
```

I've tried to set up a custom validator like so (in `child.rb`):

```
def has_one_outage
    if outages.length > 1
        errors.add(:base, "a child can only belong to one outage at a time")
    end
end
```

That validation does not seem to have an affect though.

Any insight to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: why can't you use `has_one` instead of `has_many` then?

Comment: Why not use `has_one :relationship` and `has_one :outage, :through => :relationship` on your `Child` model? The [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) describes this association.

Comment: @TomAranda right, that's what I was thinking. Tried that but that still allows children to be associated with different outages.

Comment: You may want to add a unique index like described in the linked guide.

Comment: @TomAranda you mean creating a unique index for `child_id` correct? `t.index ["child_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_child_id", unique: true`

Comment: You would want a unique composite index on both `child_id` and `outage_id` on the `relationships` table.  That way the database is enforcing that each child/outage pair is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it with the following:

```
class Outage < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :relationships
    has_many :children, through: :relationships
end


class Child < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :relationships
    has_many :outages, through: :relationships
end


  class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :child
    belongs_to :outage
    validate :ensure_one_relationship

    def ensure_one_relationship
      if Relationship.where(child_id: self.child_id).present?
          errors.add(:base, "A trouble ticket can only be associated with one outage ticket.")
      end
    end
  end
```